# How to identify Activity is launched from background

Tags: android

I am facing problem to find how to call a user defined method(Else simply Log a message) when the app becomes active that is comes to foreground from background, i.e. if user pressed home button the app goes to background when the app comes to foreground again I want to display an alert box .Can some body please tell me how to perform this check whether app has come to foreground  or provide some links .I don't understand what to search for. Some sites referred me to override `OnResume()`. However, this method is called every time my activity is launched from one activity to another even if i come back to this activity. I need this method to be called only when the user comes from background to foreground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution.

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() 
    {
        super.onPause();

        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();
        OnPause  = true;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
         OnResume = true;      
        if (!isScreenOn) 
            {
                // your code;
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();

        if(OnPause == true && OnResume == true && !isScreenOn)
        {
            YourActivity.this.finish();
        }
        isScreenOn = false;
        OnPause = false;
        OnResume = false;
    }
```

Here isScreenOn, OnPause, OnResume are boolean values.
When your mobiles screen gets lock, then the application goes in onPause() where it check for "isScreenON" and then goes in "onStop()" where isScreenOn is set to false.

When your activity comes in foreground "onResume" is called. It checks for the isScreenON and it works absolutely perfect.

Comment: I tried your code I have added a Toast message here ( // your code;)however when i first launch into the activity even then the Toast message is executed.This Toast should execute only if i come from background to foreground

Comment: boolean isScreenOn =true;

public static boolean OnPause = false;

public static boolean OnResume = false;


Set these default values for variables in your activity.

Comment: Hey Sagar thnx a ton  this works cool!!!However i want to implement this for multiple activities.Do i need to write this logic in all the classes ,i would want to make it global such that whenever i go to background and come to foreground on any of the activity my code should be called.

Comment: Hey Joyson.. even if you make a singleton class, still you have to call the function form onStop(),onResume() and onPause() functions of all the activities.

If your is too short then write the code there it self. Otherwise just call a function of your singleton class from onResume(// your code;).

If you are satisfied with the answer pleas accept the answer so that other will find it easy to use the correct code.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is simple

Consider the four methods onCreate(), onResume , onPause(), onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState).

You need to create a long Global variable for this activity

Now assign current the current time to this variable in onCreate() if your `Bundle savedInstanceState` is null other wise restore the value from savedInstanceState

In onResume Check the difference  between  current time in millsec `System.currentTimeMillis();` and this global variable, if it is greater than say 1 sec (can be higher according to your need)  display an alert box asking for password

In onPause() save the `System.currentTimeMillis();`to the global variable.

In `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` Store the value of global variable to bundle to restore in onCreate().

Sample Code

```
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        import android.app.Activity;


        public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        long timeLastPause=0;

            @Override

            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


                if(savedInstanceState==null)
                {
                    timeLastPause=System.currentTimeMillis();
//Toast.makeText(this, "App created just now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    timeLastPause=  savedInstanceState.getLong("timeLastPause");

                }





            }

            @Override
                protected void onResume() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onResume();
                    if((System.currentTimeMillis()-timeLastPause)>1000)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "the app becomes active that is comes to foreground from background", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }


            @Override
                protected void onPause() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPause();
                    timeLastPause=System.currentTimeMillis();

                }


            @Override
            protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
                outState.putLong("timeLastPause", timeLastPause);
            }


            }
```

***[EDIT]***

Ok now for any number of activities [:-0 It is tricky, Hope it will work. I implemented this in some projects and worked fine ]

In MANIFEST

```
 <application
        android:name=".TrickyApplication"
         ...
          >
```

Now create `TrickyApplication.java`

```
public class TrickyApplication extends Application {
    public long lastPause;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        lastPause = 0;
    }
}
```

Now in every activity `onResume()`

```
TrickyApplication app = ((TrickyApplication) this.getApplication());

if (System.currentTimeMillis() - app.lastPause > 1000) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Show Password Dlg Now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

and in every activity `onPause()`

```
((TrickyApplication) this.getApplication()).lastPause = System
                .currentTimeMillis();
```

Note that password dialog will be also showed for the first time you can manage this with some Shared Preference  and don't set it until your user not set a password or so then check that Pref before showing dialog

Comment: I guess the password section  is confusing my question so i edited the question.Please check it

Comment: A simple boolean would also suffice which you set in the onCreate (which will be only called once). No need for storing timings etc.

Comment: @Arun whenever i come to any activity screen FROM BACKGROUND i need to call a method(say just Log something).Its not that i need to call a method on the onresume of the activity.In simple words say there are 3 activities A,B,C.If user comes from A to B to C via intent that message should not Toast.However if user presses Home button on Activity A.Then he opens the app again (from task manager) the message should log.Similarly if he pressed home button on Activity B.The app will go to background.Now if he start the app (foreground ) he will be at Activity B then the message should Log again.

Comment: Edited it for you purpose see it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a time-out for the password. So that when the user is using the app the password will remain 'ok' for x amount of minutes.

Imagine if someone launched the app in the morning, goes back to homemenu, and launches it again in the evening you still want the user to be logged in?

The time-out date can be easily stored in SharedPreferences. (Also please don't store the password as plain text in SharedPreferences, but store a hash of it.

Comment: Yes @Rcdk.The user cannot use the app until he enters the password.This app will be used only for a single user (deviceid specific).Could u please tell me how to write a method/(which method) to identify the app has come to active state if u have a solution for it.